# Modelica - How to initialize model with previous simulation solution?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I know this issue has been raised in the past but I could not find an answer on previous conversations.

I am working with Modelica (OpenModelica v1.20.0 (64-bit)). I am simulating a dynamic system and in all simulations I have to wait for the system to reach the steady state before trying different events.
In other software, it is possible to make a "snapshot" that saves the system status at a given time, allowing one to resume the simulation from such a state.

Is there any chance of doing the same in Modelica?

I am currntly stuck in the following:

1. run the simulation that reaches the steady state (the "initialization simulation")
2. save the result in .mat format and rename it
3. in  Simulation Setup > Simulation Flags > Equation System Initialization file, I browse to the previously generated file
4. Run again

The issue is that the new simulation does not start from the last time step of the "initialization simulation"

Cheers,
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

IIRC: You have to set the `Initialization Method` to `none` so the system will be initialized from the solution you choose.